# repeating hours on X-Axis in 24 hour time series, Recharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

I have been trying to display data from server on multiple y axes scatter chart, but I have been struggling with duplicate hours on the X axis:
[image]

So far I have come up with the following code:

```
<XAxis
    dataKey='created'
    domain={['auto', 'auto']}
    name='hour'
    tickFormatter={(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('HH')}
    type='number'
    tickCount={24}
/>
```

and the data from the server comes as an array of objects:

```
{
  created: 1631199180006,
  humidity: 9,
  idStation: 3,
  name: "Sofia"
  status: "active"
  temperature: 27
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone helps to configure the domain, or give other ideas.

Comment: The only way I was able to fix a similar problem was to create a helper function to manually generate my ticks which were chosen to be aligned on-the-hour. But then I still had the problem of responsiveness, needing a larger minTickGap for smaller screens. Setting a manually generated ticks={customTickArray} seems to overrule the minTickGap prop, which does appear to work fine by itself for responsiveness. Overall, I'm not very impressed with ReCharts coming from Plotly. ReCharts does look nicer with some elbow grease but seems to lack somewhat for scientific plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using minTickGap:
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#minTickGap

```
<XAxis
    dataKey='created'
    domain={['auto', 'auto']}
    name='hour'
    tickFormatter={(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('HH')}
    type='number'
    tickCount={24}
    minTickGap={60*60*1000}
/>
```

this basically says that the minimum gap between ticks should be 1 hour.
(60 sec/min) * (60 min/hr) * (1000ms/second) gives the number of milliseconds in an hour.

Comment: This returns something different than expected - https://prikachi.net/image/zgbB0